# Toggle OnValueChanged no functions available

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial on Unity Hex Maps, which can be found here: [hex-maps part 1](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/hex-map/part-1/)

[image: HexMapEditor]

I've created a class that takes a hexgrid and allows me to set the color of a given tile. I have a public method `SelectColor(int index)` to select the color.

In order to choose the color I have a panel with 4 toggles, assigned to a toggle group.

The structure looks like this:

[image: ObjectStructure]

My problem arises when I try to set the OnValueChanged method for each toggle. There are no available options to chose from, and no other objects even to access.

This is all I have available to me:

[image: OnValueChanged]

Any ideas on how to solve or address this?

EDIT (04 Nov.):

I have updated the signature of my method to `SelectColorZero()` to test out if parameter-less functions would make a difference.

[image: NewSelectColor]

It did not.

There are still no methods available except `MonoScript.name`

EDIT (05 Nov.):

This is not a bug, this is user error. See my answer below.

Comment: the method signature needs to match the one required for the toggle, a boolean as parameter. You also need to review your implementation as index is no longer there.

Comment: @Everts actually this looks like a bug .. afaik until now you could use any `void` method with either no parameter or one single parameter of a simple type like `int` `float` `string` `bool` with a static value. What you mean is probably the `dynamic` listeners where the signature has to match the one of the according `UnityEvent<T>`

Comment: Worst case: Just make one parameter less void method for each color .. usually not what you should get used to but in this simple case it is at least a hot fix ;)

Comment: @Everts this kind of behavior is exactly what is in the tutorial though. It seems to me like it is a bug

Comment: @derHugo I have updated the method signature to `SelectColorZero()` to test it out. I still have the same issue. No additional methods are available in the drop down. I would assume this is a bug. I am using Unity 2019.2.11f1 Personal as my IDE.

Comment: @RandomnessSlayer yep sounds like a Bug! It was already broken in some of the `2019.2` releases for the [dynamic calls](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/events-generated-by-the-player-input-component-do-not-have-callbackcontext-set-as-their-parameter-type?_ga=2.135422833.1569634960.1572848206-241225422.1516255303) claims to be fixed .. but maybe in exchange something else broke? ^^

Comment: Well, yes on second thought, there is an issue. At worst, you should also see the MonoBehaviour methods. Maybe trying the classic off and back on. Unity sometimes stops working for me in the editor.

Comment: I assume your `HexMapEditor` script is attached to the `HexMapEditor` object, and that *object* is the one you've got referenced in the UnityEvent box?

Comment: @Immersive you pretty much hit the nail on the head. I was using the Asset `HexMapEditor`, when I SHOULD have been using the Scene `HexMapEditor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I was using as my Object was this:

[image: HexMapEditor Asset]

This is incorrect, notice the type: `Mono Script`

What I wanted was the Object in my Scene, over in the Scene tab, like this:

[image: HexMapEditor Scene]

And now I can set my Methods:

[image: HexMapEditor Method]

And it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have compile errors from other scripts? If so, unity won't be able to compile the scripts and you don't see your functions on the button.

You could get a refernece to your button in your script
as

```
[SerializeField] private Button greenButton;
```

and attach the onclick method via script.

```
greenButton.onclick.AddListener(Functionname);
```